# Can't get msys2 to open windows home directory on startup

Tags: shell, git-bash, msys

See [this](https://github.com/msys2/msys2/issues/56) Github issue. Basically, I am trying to launch the msys2 shell and have the startup folder (and `$HOME`) refer to my Windows user home directory. Things I've tried:

- I tried changing the `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, prepending `env windows` to `db_home` but that didn't do anything.
- I tried opening the shell in cmder with the following command:

  ```
  set MSYSTEM=MSYS & set MSYSCON=conemu64.exe & "%ConEmuDrive%\etc\msys2\usr\bin\bash.exe" --login -i" -new_console:C:"%ConEmuDrive%\etc\msys2\msys2.ico"  -new_console:d:"%USERPROFILE%"
  ```
- Modifying `/etc/profile` and adding `HOME=/c/Users/$USERNAME` to the bottom of the file. This changed the value of `~` to what I wanted, but msys2 still starts up in the old home directory.

Git-bash does this fine, and I'm wondering if there is something that git-bash is doing that I haven't set for msys2, but I can't figure it out. Any help would be great.

Comment: Wow `/c/` is a valid path to the root of the drive even though it doesn't show up in `ls /`.